# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on top points on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using a UIView with a UITapGestureRecognizer.
On the other hand I have a tap recognizer on ViewController's container view,

Now when i tap on my inner view, it calls handler,

BUT when I tap on for example 40 upper points of it, it doesn't work and container's tap recognizer fires!!!, actually i'm sure it's inside the UIView, i'm sure as I changed it's background to a different color, and on the other hand, there isn't any other views on this view, too!

It's really annoying, i've tested everything, hiding all views, disabling other recognizers and so on! And it's not my first time using this U I TAP RECOGNIZER :///

```
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewController.dismissKeyboard(_:))))
    viewWrite.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewController.viewPressed(_:))))
```

EDIT::

I found that even when i touch here on my UITextView, the main container's tap event loads!! but other points of view, no! ::

[image: HERE!!]

Comment: AND EVEN when I tap somewhere on my UITextView `dismiss keyboard` is being called!!!

Comment: Please post an image illustrating the tap position and view.

Comment: image attached @Fujia

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing *UIGestureRecognizerDelegate*

eg.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if (gestureRecognizer == recoginiser1 && wrongview1) return false
    if (gestureRecognizer == recoginiser2 && wrongview2) return false
    else return true;
}
```

wrongview means something like this.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if (gestureRecognizer == recognizer1){
    let point = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        if CGRectContainsPoint(textView.frame, point) == true {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: any view/views not required to receive touch. (eg. that UITextView that you mentioned above). eg. recogniser1 should not receive touches if touch point is in TextView (you can get touch point and the view using UITouch value)... CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:view];
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(textView.frame, point))

Comment: I know and i've tested that, not working,
I mean please add definition statement of wrongView1 to your answer.

Comment: Thanks but even now i see sometimes what i described in my edit occurs, i mean some times I log that it's returning false and sometimes it passes these conditions ! UNBELIEVABLY!!